# Error executing CustomAttributeBuilder with type XmlDocument

Tags: c#, reflection.emit, getconstructor

I have the following code as part of a system for generating interfaces using reflection.emit

```
class Class1:Attribute 
{
    public Class1(XmlDocument doc) 
    {
    }
}

var type = typeof(Class1);
var ctore = type.GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(XmlDocument) });
var cab = new CustomAttributeBuilder(ctore, new object[] { new XmlDocument() });
```

For reasons unknown to me, the program generates an error:

> In an argument, field, or property used designer custom attribute type is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See remarks section of [CustomAttributeBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3te85bew%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation:

> The elements of the constructorArgs array are restricted to element
>   types. They can be byte, sbyte, int, uint, long, ulong, float, double,
>   String, char, bool, an enum, a type, any of the previous types that
>   was cast to an object, or a single-dimension, zero-based array of any
>   of the previous types.

You cannot use `XmlDocument` type as a constructor argument, because its not in list. This restriction goes from C# attribute parameters restriction. See [17.1.3 Attribute parameter types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664615%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) section of C# specification for list of acceptable parameter types:

- One of the following types: bool, byte, char, double, float, int, long, short, string.
- The type object.
- The type System.Type.
- An enum type, provided it has public accessibility and the types in
  which it is nested (if any) also have public accessibility (Section
  17.2).
- Single-dimensional arrays of the above types.

Constructor `public Class1(XmlDocument doc)` is completely valid for regular C# class, and you can declare it in attribute class. But you can't use it when you'll apply attribute to your code. And this is goal of any attribute class. So, despite you can declare such constructor, it makes no sense for attribute class.

Comment: Can you tell me why they don't include decimal as a valid type? The same rules apply for properties and fields in a CustomAttributeBuilder that apply for constructors apparently, and when I set some property values that were decimal I came up with the same error. So the only workaround that I can think of, which I hate to do and completely defeats the point, is to pass in a string as a constructor argument as JSON in a new constructor for my custom attribute types and have it set the properties by Reflection after deserialization. This is a serious limitation of CustomAttributeBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. I will use the class XmlAttributeAttribute. Thank you.